# Ubuntu Install Packages of Older Version

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to install some applications/ packages that were available for Ubuntu 18.04 on Ubuntu 18.10. In my special case it is the Deepin Desktop Environment, but there are other packages, too.

From the instructions on the net I learned to do it with the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dde
```

Then I get the following output/ error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dde
```

I figure that either Ubuntu or Deepin are not maintaining the package.

My question is: is it possible - speaking in general terms, not only for this specific application - to install a package of an older version on a newer version, when the package cannot be located in the repositories of the newer version? If yes, what would be the proceedings?

Comment: Did `sudo apt-get update` give any errors about no release-file or similar. It would be somewhat easier to help you if you updated your question with the full output of the commands you whare running.

Comment: done so ... kindly see my edit

Comment: That ppa does not provide `dde` for cosmic, only artful and bionic and I don't find any other option. You should use 18.04 or Manjaro Deepin